# how to subscribe to usb_cam/image_raw to process the image from camera?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what is missing in the below code that is used for subscribing to the topic /usb_cam/image_raw.

```
void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "main");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

  std::cout<<"Subscribing starts!"<<std::endl;
  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("usb_cam/image_raw", 2, chatterCallback);

  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

how to get the image from the camera so that i need to process this image. Is there any files missing in the header.

```
~/usb_cam/launch$ rostopic info /usb_cam/image_raw
Type: std_msgs/String

Publishers: None

Subscribers: 
 * /listener (http://ubuntu:42711/)
 * /main (http://ubuntu:35605/)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250734/how-to-subscribe-to-usb_cam/image_raw-to-process-the-image-from-camera?/) by [chaiein](https://answers.ros.org/users/20827/chaiein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*image_raw* is most probably a sensor_msgs/Image and not a std_msgs/String so you will need to change the callback function to expect this data type.

So rather

```
void chatterCallback(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  ROS_INFO("Received image with size: %i x %i", msg->width, msg->height);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0